# Laravel dump() function and memory leaks

Tags: php, laravel, memory-leaks

I had a memory leak problem inside a custom artisan command I made for a project.
This method made some operations and, for debugging purpose, I printed to terminal many times the variables used in the script using dump() (the laravel helper function that replaces var_dump and print_r).
The problem was that the memory used increased on every iteration of the loop causing a fatal error.
I lost many hours finding out what was the problem, and finally I found the solution: I stopped using dump() function inside the script.
Is it possible that multiple dump() calls increase memory usage? And why?

Comment: Digging a bit into the source it seems that each variable you pass to the var dumper is cloned and then is kept in a cache along with a unique hash. Presumably this is to handle cycles or prevent extra work that would arise from cloning the same variable again. This would have the side-effect that if you dump many distinct variables each one will take up memory [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.3/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Cloner/VarCloner.php#L20) (the VarCloner is in practice a singleton here)

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I can tell you that Laravel's dumper is actually [Symfony's](https://github.com/symfony/var-dumper) which might help you with your searches

Comment: @apokryfos you're right. Your comment is the answer I needed. Thank you